# SQL Server select by grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, grouping

Table 1

csstatus

```
csid status
122  defaulter
123  regular
124  registery
125  defaulter
```

table 2

csplotdetials

```
csid plotsize
122  50
123  25
124  30
125  25
```

qunery result

```
Status     totalplotsize

defaulter  75
regular    25
....
```

how i can do that both tables are not in relationship they are in realtionship with another table

Comment: Why status `defaulter` has `totalplotsize` = 75? where it has only one entry with 50 in the second table?? Also please post the other table and its relation with these two tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT status, sum(plotsize) as totalplotsize 
FROM csstatus cs 
INNER JOIN csplotdetials cp ON cs.csid = cp.csid 
GROUP BY status
```

Comment: Why -1 when the query is proper?

Comment: Not sure, but I got one too :(

Answer (score 0):

I must be missing something here, because it looks like I can infer a relationship between the two tables (on the `csid` column) to produce the results you are after:

```
SELECT csstatus.status AS Status, SUM(csplotdetials.plotsize) AS totalplotsize
FROM csplotdetials
INNER JOIN csstatus ON csplotdetials.csid = csstatus.csid
GROUP BY csstatus.status
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/028d7/1)

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that tables are linked via `csID` coluymn from both tables.

```
SELECT  a.csID, a.status, SUM(b.plotsize) totalPlotSize
FROM    ccstatus a
        INNER JOIN csplotdetails b
            On a.csID = b.csID
GROUP   BY a.csID, a.status
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7479b/2)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)